# Unexplained json .has("key") fatal exception, from one day to another

Tags: android, json, eclipse, nullpointerexception, fatal-error

This weekend something strange happened on my app. 
Before Thursday I had been using this instruction without problems:

```
if(!jsonL2.has("counters"))
```

By Sunday, the app was suffering a fatal exception in that line of code
and I had to use a temporary boolean variable to avoid the exception:

```
Boolean s =jsonL2.has("counters"); //Works!
if(s==false){
```

It is a Null Pointer exception. Somehow, when Json.has("key") is inside the IF statement, it returns null when evaluated if the Key is not found. (instead of returning False!)

If I take Json.has("key") outside the IF condition, it -does- return False when the key is not found.
This did not happen before.

Can somedoy explain this? Does the Rules of programming change from one day to
another while Eclipse updates itself silently in the backgroud?

Here is the full code with the changes:

```
//if(!jsonL2.has("counters")){     //BAD!! Fatal Exception after June 15
Boolean s =jsonL2.has("counters"); //Works!
if(s==false){                      //Works!
    httpbusy=false;
    i= new Intent();
    i.putExtra("NAVIGATION", "summary");
    releaseCamera();                                        
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, i);             
    finish();
}
```

Comment: So, what is the fatal exception? We can't help unless you post it...

Comment: @TassosBassoukos Sorry, I edited the post to describe it better, you can now check it.

Comment: This makes no sense. Have you tried a clean build? What is the class of the exception being thrown? (It may be thrown and caught internally but your debugging is breaking, in which case it is normal).